# Searching for a Facebook venue using geolocation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation, facebook-fql

I'm trying to retrieve a venue's information by searching for it using a particular geolocation on facebook. I'm trying to do this using FQL.

For example, I want to retrieve a Starbucks places info (I know the Starbucks is actually there), so far i have come up with:

```
SELECT name, description, latitude, longitude, checkin_count
FROM place 
where page_id in ( SELECT page_id from place where name = 'Starbucks' ) and distance(latitude, longitude, "9.961718","-84.054542") < 1000
```

But unfortunately I only get the following error

> "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an
>   indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked
>   from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql "

Does someone know what am i doing wrong or how to do what i'm trying to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### FQL answer (deprecated)

*Since FQL is deprecated and unusable, you will now find the FQL way of doing this in the revision history of this post.*

#### Graph API (up-to-date)

To find a place, you can use the [Graph API Search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/).

> **Places:** `/search?q=coffee&type=place`.  You can
>   narrow your search to a specific location and distance by adding the
>   center parameter (with latitude and longitude) and an optional
>   distance parameter: 
>   `/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000`

So, the Graph API query that might interest you, would be:

```
/search?q=Starbucks&type=place&center=9.961718,-84.054542&distance=1000
```

Also, note that `distance` represents meters.